# semantic release does not generate release on a branches needed

Tags: git, github, devops, semantic-release

I am using semantic-rlease library and here is my release.config.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  branch: 'rel',
  dryRun: false,
  debug: true,
  repositoryUrl: 'https://github.xxx.com/xxx/backend',
  githubUrl: 'https://github.ibm.com/',
  githubApiPathPrefix: '/api/v3',
  verifyConditions: ['@semantic-release/github', '@semantic-release/changelog'],
  verifyRelease: [],
  publish: ['@semantic-release/github'],
  prepare: ['@semantic-release/changelog'],
  success: ['@semantic-release/github'],
  generateNotes: ['@semantic-release/release-notes-generator'],
  fail: ['@semantic-release/github'],
  plugins: [
    '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer',
    ['@semantic-release/changelog', {
      changelogFile: 'docs/CHANGELOG.md',
    }],
    ['@semantic-release/github', {

    }],
  ],
  preset: 'angular',
};
```

As you see I have rel branch set as a branch to generate the semantic release and it works fine but as soon as I change the above to

```
   require('dotenv').config();
    module.exports = {
      branches: ['(rel|release|Relite)?(-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+)','rel'],
      ...
```

in order to generate release for any of the branch name like : rel-1.0.0 or release-1.3.4 or rel.
and I am in for example rel-1.0.2 I get a message saying semantic release is set to master so it wont generate the release

```
This test run was triggered on the branch rel-1.0.0, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from master, therefore a new version won’t be published.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try commit changes on file that holds you release config before testing again.